# Load .so lib error: no such file or directory in linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

I have a .so lib and put it in `/home/xxx/MediaConfig`. I created a `.cc` file and open the lib with:

```
dlopen("./xxx.so",RTLD_LAZY)
```

But the output of console is always

> can not open the shared libary: no such file or directory

What's wrong with it?

I compile it with:

```
g++ -m32 -g TestC.cc -o TestC -ldl
```

And the .cc file is also in the MediaConfig directory.

Comment: Is the .so file 32bit too?

Comment: Does it work if you pass an absolute path to `dlopen` instead of a relative one?

Comment: the lib is 32bit,if i delete -m32, it will display wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32. if I change the load directory to /home/xxx/MediaConfig/xxx.so, the result is the same.

Comment: I also think the error message indicates that either path or filename is wrong.

Comment: Use `ldd` to check what other .so files `xxx.so` needs and make sure that they are installed on your system. If the loader can not find these, the loading of the .so fails.